# how to convert/import/create a CSV file to excel (xlsx) using C# forms

Tags: parsing, csv, xlsx

I am trying to convert CSV file to MS Excel file.
one of the issue, is that my CSV file , which I am getting from client, is not well formed. I tried to parse it with different approach but none of them end up with expected results.
therefore I had to manually open the CSV file in Excel and save it as .xlsx and then use it for data import.
But I want automate this change. i.e. an application which I give CSV file path and in response it generates a proper .xlsx file.

Thanks